# How to iterate over an object list containing child objects and create another custom object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object list like this, I am getting this response from one of the api:

```
  {
        "1/22/20": {
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 1,
        },
        "1/23/20": {
            "new_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 10,
        },
        "1/24/20": {
            "new_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 20
        }
  }
```

Expected Output:

```
{
   x:1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20 // key of every object
   y:1,10,20 //total_cases
 }
```

Please help me how can we achieve this. I tried `object.stringify` but its not giving me an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) & [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) methods for this like:

```js
const data = {
        "1/22/20": {
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 1,
        },
        "1/23/20": {
            "new_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 10,
        },
        "1/24/20": {
            "new_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 20
        }
  }

const keys = Object.keys(data).join(',')
const cases = Object.entries(data).map(([k,v]) => v).map(x=>x.total_cases).join(',')
const result = { x: keys, y: cases}
console.log(result)
```

---

> output as {x:1/22/20, y:1}, {x:1/23/20,y:10}

```js
const data = {
        "1/22/20": {
            "new_daily_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 1,
        },
        "1/23/20": {
            "new_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 10,
        },
        "1/24/20": {
            "new_deaths": 0,
            "total_cases": 20
        }
  }

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([k,v]) => ({x: k, y: v.total_cases}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: And if I would like to get output as `{x:1/22/20, y:1}, {x:1/23/20,y:10}` and so on?

Comment: You can simply do: const result = Object.entries(data).map(([k,v]) => ({x: k, y: v.total_cases})) I have also added a demo.